# spacy-pytorch-transformers: loss = 0 constantly during training

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, spacy, spacy-transformers

I'm using `spacy 2.1.8` and `spacy-pytorch-transformers 0.4.0` to train a text classifier. My code is strongly inspired from their [example](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-pytorch-transformers/blob/master/examples/train_textcat.py) but the model is not learning anything, which seems to be caused by the loss being 0 all the time. A minimum (not-)working example of my code is as follows:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_pytt_xlnetbasecased_lg")
textcategorizer = nlp.create_pipe("pytt_textcat", config={"exclusive_classes": True, "architecture": "softmax_last_hidden"})

for label in labels:
    textcategorizer.add_label(label)
nlp.add_pipe(textcategorizer, last=True)

optimizer = nlp.resume_training()

for epoch in range(num_of_epochs):
    np.random.shuffle(train)
    losses = Counter()

    for step, batch in enumerate(minibatch(train, size=batch_size)):
        optimizer.pytt_lr = 0.005
        texts, cats = zip(*batch)
        _, cats = preprocessed_labels_to_categories_for_training_and_eval(cats)

        nlp.update(texts, cats, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses, drop=0.1)
```

I already double and triple checked that relevant variables, such as `cats` and `texts`, contain valid and correct values.

Is there anything I'm missing?